# Testing Google Android Places Autocomplete with Espresso

Tags: android, android-studio, ui-testing, android-espresso

I'm struggling with instrumental ui test of a PlaceAutocomplete API, provided by Google.

What I'm trying to test is ability to open AutoComplete Activity (fired with proper button), enter some text, pick result from given list and check if picked position is listed on the recyclerview.

I'm trying to target this EditText below :(

[image: Screenshot of ui automater]

with:

```
   onView(withClassName(equalTo(EditText.class.getName())))
                .inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(homeActivityActivityTestRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
                .perform(typeTextIntoFocusedView("kotek"), closeSoftKeyboard());
```

And other variations, like withText "Szukaj" or with com.google.android.gms.R.id :) without luck.

Help will be appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: add your layout xml

Comment: What does "without luck" mean? Please be more specific.

Comment: It means that no matter how I try I can't target this EditText. Espresso seems to ignore this whole autocomplete widget.

Comment: @piotrek1543 This view is auto-generated by Google Api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This view is auto-generated by Google Api.

If it's true, sorry I haven't any experience with Places API, it would mean that Espresso is unable to find this view.

#### Solution: `Espresso Test Recorder`

You can install the latest Android Studio 2.2-RC2 (don't remove the previous) from: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-2-rc to check brand new `Espresso Test Recorder` (check: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/test-recorder) and try to get this view by click on this to generate code, but I said this might not help.

#### Solution: `Espresso` with `uiatomator`

My doubts about it come from `Espresso` framework limitation - it depends on actual context of app, it means that it may not recognize intents, genereated code or notifications.

Try to use typical instrumentation framework like Google's `uiatomator`. There's no problem to use it along with `Espresso` UI testing framework.

Read: http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html

More info you would find here: http://google.github.io/android-testing-support-%20/docs/uiautomator/

#### Solution: `Espresso` with `Robotium` or `Robotium Test Recorder`

If you find `uiatomator` a pretty hard to learn you can also use another instrumentation test framework called `Robotium`, which has clean and conchise syntax with some powerfull functions like taking screenshots.

It can work along with Espresso. Check last paragraph of this article: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/UI-Testing-with-Robotium

It also has its own recorder: http://robotium.com/products/robotium-recorder. Try it for free, but I doubt that you would find it useful, as `Robotium` code is really simple to learn.

Hope it will help

Comment: Unfortunately Espresso Test Recorder also failed. Your suspicion about seeing only current(app) context is correct. Well...I think I'll pass on this one and try to refactor this feature in order to communicate with Google Api without using external widgets. But hey! Tool is amazing! Thank you!

Comment: @Krzysztof Don't miss Robotium and uiautomator. they are also powerful. If you could reward my answer and what,s more - time and knowledge, i would be happy :-) Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Install Android studio 2.2 Beta, Try the Espresso test recorder. It will automatically generate an Espresso test case for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this one :-**

```
  Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.places_autocomplete_edit_text))
            .perform(ViewActions.typeText("<ADDRESS>"))
        Thread.sleep(3000);
  onView(withText("<ADDRESS FROM SUGESSION>"))
            .inRoot(withDecorView(Matchers.not(activityTestRule.activity.window.decorView)))
            .perform(click())
```

**Tested with :-** Android Studio:3.5.2 | espresso-core:3.1.1 | places:1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Autocompleater component seems to be not accessible using espresso, one solution is to send typing then clicking through a shell

```
getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("input text n")
sleep(2000)
getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("input tap " + Math.round(width / 2f) + " " + Math.round(height / 4f))
```